# I want to load tables dynamically from SharePoint as per user's click in existing slicer view in Power BI Desktop. Can Anybody have idea about that?

Tags: powerbi, sharepoint-2010

I had created few pages of projects in Power BI Report.
Now I have to load  data dynamically from SharePoint to  Power BI when user click any project name from existing visualization.

Then after new visualization will be created as per requirements.

I had try to load multiple table from SharePoint to Power BI & by using Append Query combine tables but there are more than 300 tables so its getting huge time.

I am Trying REST API as well but not success yet...